# Oracle Sequence nextval is jumping number back and forth

Tags: c#, sql, database, oracle, sequence

I created a new table and a new sequence, I have two C# web services trying to insert records into this table using same query utilizing `mySequence.nextval` (and yes I checked it many times, they both use `mySequence.nextval`).

The two web services are inserting rows to the table, but the `mySequence.nextval` is returning numbers out of sequence

Here is how the records were created, showing `PrimaryKey` which gets its value from `mySequence.nextval`

> 1 21 22 23 2 3 24 25 4 27 28 5

So far no duplicates but why is `mySequence.nextval` jumping back and forth? and should I worry about it

**Update:**
The sequence is created with cache_size = 20

Comment: Why down voting a serious valid question?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I will wager that your database is running RAC (Real Application Clusters).  Assuming that is the case and that you create the sequence with all the default settings, that's the expected behavior.

The default setting is to cache 20 values.  Each node in the RAC cluster, by default, will have a separate cache.  Assuming that you have a cluster with two nodes A and B, the first time a `nextval` is requested on A, A will cache values 1-20 and return a value of 1.  If the next request for a `nextval` is made on B, B will cache values 21-40 and return a value of 21.  From there, the value you get will depend on the node that your connection happens to be running on.

Generally, this shouldn't be a problem.  Sequences generate unique numbers.  The numbers generally need not be consecutive.  If you really need values to be returned sequentially because you are doing something like ordering by the sequence-generated value to determine the "first" or "last" row, you can use the `ORDER` clause when you create the sequence to force values to be returned in order.  That has a negative performance implication in a RAC database, however, because it increases the amount of communication that needs to go on between the nodes to synchronize the values being returned.  If you need to determine the "first" or "last" row, it's generally better to add a `date` or a `timestamp` column to the table and order by that rather than assuming that the primary key is generated sequentially.

Comment: This was the reason, disabling the sequence cache seems to be fixing it. I'm not worried about the very small impact on performance.

Comment: @DownMasters.com - Specifying `ORDER` when creating the sequence would be preferrable to setting the cache to 1 (you have to have some cache).  It's a bit more efficient and it guarantees that the values are returned in order.  Theoretically, you could get values out of order if you have set the cache to 1 unless you created the sequence as an ordered sequence.  I don't know of a reason that a sequence with a cache of 1 and `noorder` specified would actually return values out of order, at least with the current version of Oracle.  That may change in the future though.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs...

*Sequence numbers are generated independently of tables, so the same sequence can be used for one or for multiple tables. It is possible that individual sequence numbers will appear to be skipped, because they were generated and used in a transaction that ultimately rolled back. Additionally, a single user may not realize that other users are drawing from the same sequence.*

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314

Comment: this is a brand new table and brand new sequence, I'm 100% sure no one is using this sequence somewhere else

Comment: Really? 100% sure? Did you run a trace? YOU are probably accessing it without knowing it. I've done that before. Some of the visual tools run queries that will increment the sequence. At any rate, my point is don't worry about it. If you need to garauntee no gaps, standard sequences aren't the right tool. If you use sequences there will always be gaps eventually.

Comment: Brand new sequence, I'm not accessing it from anywhere else.

Comment: And yet, you are. You accepted the other answer, which provides the detail about where else you are accessing it, but this is still the answer. People can spend their rep down-voting this if they want, but it only lacks detail. This IS your problem, if the answer you accepted is correct. Multiple accesses were happening and you didn't know about it.

Comment: Not so much a lack of detail, but merely answering the wrong question. The question wasn't about skipped values but about the *order* in which those values appeared. The correct answer was provided by Justin. /2c

Comment: LOL, your question wasn't that good. You don't give anywhere near enough detail to make that other answer the only possible correct one. You asked why the sequence is jumping around, and this is a reason why. It's not THE reason why, but there's no way to know that from your question.